# Convert String to time in PHP

Tags: php, time

I get the string data from the database
The data format like:

```
07:00:00.0000000
```

It means 7:00 am.
How can i convert this string into Date type for comparison.
Therefore, I can get 2 data. Such as

```
Start:
07:00:00.0000000
End:
16:30:00.0000000
```

After the time comparison, i can got a answer like 9.3.

Comment: How can you extract the date from this?

Comment: Did you mean `date and time` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `strtotime` :

```
$start = strtotime("07:00:00.0000000");
$end   = strtotime("16:30:00.0000000");

$difference = $end - $start;
```

Or with DataTime object :

```
$start = new DateTime("07:00:00.0000000");
$end   = new DateTime("16:30:00.0000000");

$interval   = $start->diff($end);
$difference = $end->getTimestamp() - $start->getTimestamp();
```

Then `echo` the result :

```
echo $difference;            // in seconds
echo $difference / 60;       // in minutes
echo $difference / 3600;     // in hours

echo $interval->format('%s') // in seconds
```

It's then up to your preference. I also suggest you to have a look at [this post](http://en.code-bude.net/2013/12/19/benchmark-strtotime-vs-datetime-vs-gettimestamp-in-php/) regarding the performances of the two solutions.

Comment: Can the downvoter explain himself ?

Comment: I did not downvote, but I can only guess it's because you've chosen to use `strtotime` rather than PHP's `DateTime` objects.

Comment: Well, I think there is no need here to use objects, but anyway, I edited to add an example with the use of DateTime object.

Comment: Hint: If you're using DateTime objects, take a peek at the diff function :) http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php

Comment: @Duroth you're right, in case, I edited to add an example with it.